# Is the add landscape button really just a pre-made Mt. McKinely?

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

In the add mesh menu, If you click on the button labeled *Landscape*, It will add a relatively cool looking mesh.

[image: Add mesh menu]

However, once I put my favorite color on it, This mesh seems pretty useless.

[image: Screenshot of blue mesh]

It actually looks kinda like Mt. McKinely

[image: Picture from Wikipedia]

The only possible use I can see is if I wanted to go into sculpt mode and modify it further, Then it could have some use as a base mesh to save you some time instead of sculpting from a plane. Is there actually any practical reason to use this button? or is this feature just another pre-made mesh like **Suzanne** and **teapot**?

Comment: did you try adjusting the presets to get different results ?

Comment: well it also kinda looks like longs peak or mt. democrat so I think it's just a generic seed that looks like a random mountain. You can change the seed number to get different "mountains" but the landscape is really just a randomly genrated bumpy thing with a falloff vector. if you get rid off the falloff, (set to "none") you can see that it could also look exactly like the bottom of the ocean blue, home sweet home for us both. It's called "we see what we want to see".

Comment: You might want to look on this rather good tutorial about using the addon - https://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/creating-an-island-environment-in-blender. I have learned this addon from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the settings for the *ANT* landscape creation by moving the random seed:

[image]

**By the way** *ANT* refers to ***[Another Noise Tool](https://developer.blender.org/T23130)***

Comment: well there goes my answer. :(

Comment: I can not seem to find that menu to change the settings now that I have added the landscape and changed the color.

Comment: You can only change the settings in creation. Once you change anything else you can't go back. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: if you want to change the landscape interacively you can try using a displace modifier with a noise texture see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454