# Generate realistic mountains

Tags: objects

I am looking to  generate realistic mountains, preferably using the addon ANT landscape generator. I am looking for a mountain like this.[image: http://i.amz.mshcdn.com/SmI6btp_-GTyjXFuXFMNRe_1dXY=/fit-in/850x850/http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2Fwp-content%2Fgallery%2F25-photorealistic-landscapes-that-would-bring-bob-ross-to-tears%2FBen%2520Pretorius.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

CynicatPro to the rescue! You can actually download and import real world terrain data into Blender. This video shows you how. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_615645983&feature=iv&src_vid=A-OfeO7H0Mk&v=cZxyN7esQkY

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/is-the-add-landscape-button-really-just-a-pre-made-mt-mckinely/28015#28015