# I need to do a very simple terrain with texture map

Tags: modeling, uv, modifiers, displacement

I know nothing about Blender and I need to do a very simple 3D terrain with texture map.

I have a 1000 x 700 height map:
[image]

And I have a 1000 x 700 texture map:
[image]

And I want to combine them into a 3D model that I can view. I have done this before, about 8 years ago, in XNA but none of my old code will compile anymore under Visual Studio 2010.

I apologize that this is a very simple question. I'm not a CGI artist and I don't anything about Blender but I know that it can do this simple thing.

What are the steps to do this with Blender?

Thanks for posting the steps but I don't have Import -> images as planes. I just have this:
[image]

Am I in the wrong place?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31352/1853

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import the height map using ***Import images as planes***.

Enter edit mode and subdivide the mesh like a 100 times.

[image]

Add a **Displacement** modifier.

[image]

Set the texture to use the height map. Set the color space to Non-Color (height maps should be treated as data, and have no "gamma" curves)

[image]

Don't worry if the displacement seems exaggerated for now.

Back in the displacement modifier, set the displacement axis to **Normal** and to use the **UV** map.

The height for the displacement can be conrolled moving the strength slider.

For a better level of detail add a subsurf modifier before the displacement:

[image]

(be careful not to set the subsurf modifer to a high number, 1 or 2 subdivision levels should be enough, otherwise you might end up with an unmanageable amount of vertices and your computer might slow down or crash)

Then assign the color texture image as the color for your material.

[image]

Why the funky edges on the surface? Your height map needs a bit of cleanup before doing all of this

NOTE:

Usually the import images as planes plugin is enabled by default. If it isn't, you'll have to enable it manually. In the top menu find **Edit** > **Preferences**. Then from menu navigate to the add-ons section and find Import-Export: Import Images as Planes.

To enable the add on check on the box to the left of the add on name:

[image]

---

For versions previous to 2.8 the settings can be found here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Or just scale down the UVs so the edges aren't used.