# Strange edges on height map

Tags: height-map

Following the steps in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57943/i-need-to-do-a-very-simple-terrain-with-texture-map) question has yielded some pretty good results. I have just one issue, which was also experienced in the original question. The edges of my height map are oddly high.

I loaded the DEM in GIS software, and here are no odd values; QGIS tells me that those pixels are marked as "no data". This leads me to conclude that the issue is happening in Blender. The answer in the original question tells the questioner to clean up his height map, but how is this done, especially when the edge-errors do not appear to exist in the DEM.

Edges in Blender (camera rotated to make edges more apparent):
[image: Edges]

No edges in QGIS:
[image: no edges]

Comment: Are you using linear interpolation for the texture? Have you tried with Closest interpolation? Can you provide the source image file?

Comment: Thank you! This and changing the image extrapolation fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean distortion around object's edge, change image extrapolation to **Extend**.

Displacement Modifier > Texture Properties > Mapping

[image]

... in case you use Subdivision Modifier > Adaptive Subdivision:

[image]