# how to insert a height map to a sphere and create a high poly planet?

Tags: modeling

https://www.renderhub.com/users/w/i/r/wirecase3d/3d-model-earth-globe-hd/
that is Earth which is what I wanted to create. I want to know how I can possibly create Earth like this, very high detailed. All Im asking for is a tutorial video to learn how to insert a height map to a sphere.

Comment: To unwrap a sphere see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere/13928#13928 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/uv-sphere-unwrap-perfect-square/84859#84859

Comment: To add a height map: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57943/i-need-to-do-a-very-simple-terrain-with-texture-map/57945#57945 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31350/re-do-view-of-a-photo-via-dem-data-and-blender/31352#31352

Comment: Then use a decimate modifier to optimize the geometry.