# How to use displacement modifier?

Tags: displacement

I am following tutorials that simply says to add a mesh, then add a modifier for displacement and voilà, their mesh turns into some cool looking shape.

Whenever I do that nothing happens...

I have tried using the Cycles engine with and without experimental.

I have tried using the Displacement NODE in materials.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_e4t1uaXk6U&feature=youtu.be

Why doesn't my displacement work?

Comment: Please edit your question an add information, add images that show your current project and the settings you are using. Format the question so that users have to go to a link just to understand the question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link to a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449) While videos and images are helpful in diagnosing the issue, they should be supplemental to the question and complement a written description of the issue, not a replacement, ideally with accompanying images showing the problem. You should edit your question remove any "introductory text" and replace it with an actually explaination of what the issue is and what steps you took to attempt to solve it

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work, it seems to work, we can see some displacements on the surface of your sphere...

Comment: How many levels of subdivision did you use? Higher (5-6) is generally required to show the detail correctly.

Comment: I am using 5 levels. Yes it is adding a bit of displacement, but at those settings it is no where near what happens when I follow the tutorials. and no matter what settings I use it just makes it look like a slight orange peel.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454

Comment: No, that is not the problem. I knew how to USE displacement. The issue resides in that Blender updated their engine. I had to go into the Shader tab and add a DISPLACEMENT node and connect it to the Displacement of the Material output. Then I had to go to the engine and use CYCLES. After I had to go to the materials settings and change from "BUMP ONLY" to "DISPLACEMENT and BUMP". It really wasn't simple at all.

Comment: Adaptive subdiv displacement/material displacement is NOT the same as the displace modifier. Nothing changed. There's no issue. It's just two different methods of achieving two similar, but different results.

Comment: If you actually check out the new Blender updates, Displace modifier will not work unless displacement is added to the shader material output displacement node input as well as set engine to Cycles and set displacement to Displacement AND Bump in materials details.